# #await blocks in an #each loop and DOM refresh performance issue

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm looping through items I retrieved from a Sveltekit store, and retrieving additional information asynchronously for each of the iterated items.

The simplified code looks like:

```html
        {#each $order.itemIDs as itemID}
          {#await calcItemPrice(itemID)}
          {:then price}
            {#await itemFor(itemID)}
            {:then item}
              <OrderItem itemID={item._id} description={item.description} price={price} />
            {/await}
          {/await}
        {/each}
```

Separately, the UI allows to add more entries (with `update`) to `$order.itemIDs`, which triggers a redrawing of the DOM elements in the each loop. The key problems with this are:

- Redrawing the `#each` loop every time an item is added means remaking the asynchronous calls for each of the items every time. This clearly impact performance as more and more items are added.
- During this (slow) redrawing, DOM elements in the `#each` flash as they disappear from a moment and reappear once all fetch queries have been performed.

I think my question is two-fold:

- How can I make it so that adding a new `itemID` to `$order.itemIDs` will not trigger a redraw of all the rendered elements, but instead just append the new element to the DOM?
- At what time should I run my asynchronous call to improve rendering performance? (I have a feeling than running at rendering time is suboptimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first thing to do would be to use a keyed each block instead, this will make that only the items that have changed actually get re-rendered:

```
{#each $order.itemIDs as itemID (itemID)}
```

Make sure the ID you use is unique, the above is just an example!

---

That said, I would not use an await block in a loop, I believe that is just asking for problems down the line.  See if it can be possible to load those items elsewhere instead, perhaps with an await block for the very first run.

How to implement this would of course heavily depend on your use case and requirements, one idea could be to have another array that is populated from the store:

```js
let items = []

async function loadItems(stored) {
  const changed = stored.filter(s => !items.some(s => s.id == s));
  const result = await Promise.all(changed.map(async => calcsHere))
  items = [...items, ...result];
}

$: loadItems($order.itemIDs)
```

The above code declares an array `items` and a function `loadItems` that will run every time the store changes.
What the function itself does is:

- filter out the items that are *new* (to not refetch them)
- fire off fetches for all new items simultaneously and wait for all them to return
- add the new items to the old items

(Note that I might have plenty of errors in that code, it's just a general concept)

One downside of this is that you do cannot have a 'loading' indicator, although you could perhaps do that by pushing the new items to the array with some kind of 'loading' flag and then overwriting them.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I tried the key, however it seems to have no effect here, maybe because svelte can't determine whether the DOM element will change or not due to the async nature of the content?

Reading at the doc, seems like the default behaviour is what I want.

"If a key expression is provided [...] Svelte will use it to diff the list when data changes, *rather than adding or removing items at the end.*"

I will try a `loadItems` function as suggested, and come back here.

Comment: Tip: `indicator = Promise.all(...); const result = await indicator`; allows showing a spinner with {#await indicator}Loading...{/if}